# How to know if a ID has a parent ID or not in WIQL TFS?

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops, wiql

I have an id and I want to know if has a `parentid` or not by C# coding for TFS.  In my TFS board there are many user stories that do not include a `Feature` ?

My hierarchical structure in TFS is as follows:

```
Feature
--->User Stories(u1,u2,u3)
--->Tasks (t1,t2,t3)
```

Sometimes a user story does not contain a `Feature`

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-dotnet-samples/blob/master/ClientLibrary/Snippets/Microsoft.TeamServices.Samples.Client/WorkItemTracking/WorkItemsSample.cs#L98 User story with certain links???

Comment: no i want to know if user story cantains parent or not

Comment: thats what links are. if not why not look at the api docs

Comment: how to know if it's parent or child ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this with direct workitem query. You may create it in VS and save to local drive:
[image]

Then you may find query text in saved query:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><WorkItemQuery Version="1"><TeamFoundationServer>http://myserverandcollection</TeamFoundationServer><TeamProject>MyProject</TeamProject><Wiql>
SELECT [System.Id], [System.Links.LinkType], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State], [System.Tags] FROM WorkItemLinks WHERE ([Source].[System.Id] = 174) And ([System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse') And ([Target].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Feature') ORDER BY [System.Id] mode(MustContain)
</Wiql></WorkItemQuery>
```

Then you may create application with Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient nugate package

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace QueryLinkedWIQL
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WorkItemStore _wistore = new WorkItemStore("http://myserver/myCollection");

            int _id = 175;
            string _wiql = String.Format("SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItemLinks WHERE ([Source].[System.Id] = {0}) And ([System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse') And ([Target].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Feature') ORDER BY [System.Id] mode(MustContain)", _id);

            Query _query = new Query(_wistore, _wiql);

            WorkItemLinkInfo[] _links = _query.RunLinkQuery();

            if (_links.Count() == 2) //only 1 child and its parent
                Console.WriteLine("Parent ID: " + _links[1].TargetId);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("There is no parent for ID: " + _id);
        }
    }
}
```

===========================for Relation Task->Something->Feature============

You may use tree query:

[image]

and this code:

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace QueryLinkedWIQL
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WorkItemStore _wistore = new WorkItemStore("http://myserver/myCollection");

            int _id = 210;
            string _wiql = String.Format("SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItemLinks WHERE ([Source].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Feature') And ([System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward') And ([Target].[System.Id] = {0}  AND  [Target].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Task') ORDER BY [System.Id] mode(Recursive,ReturnMatchingChildren)", _id);

            Query _query = new Query(_wistore, _wiql);

            WorkItemLinkInfo[] _links = _query.RunLinkQuery();

            if (_links.Count() > 1) //first item contains feature
                Console.WriteLine("Parent ID: " + _links[0].TargetId);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("There is no parent for ID: " + _id);
        }
    }
}
```

---------Screens

Query:

[image]

Debug:

[image]

[image]

Comment: can i know if a Task has a feature ID ?

Comment: This example use any work item type (task, user story, bug) with known id (int _id = 175;) to find its parent feature ID. "_links[1].TargetId" contains feature ID.

Comment: i want to find task featureid

Comment: It was test on my vsts account, screens added to main answer.

Comment: could u help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48921922/how-to-find-all-the-sprint-work-in-tfs-by-wiql-c-sharp-code

Comment: need 2 more Query task's that does not have User storyies in whole project MRI_SCRUm  and (Task that does not have user stories)

Comment: You may change "[Source].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Feature'" to "[Source].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Task'" in last example and you'll get tree with Task->Task. Also you may change "[Source].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Feature'" to "[Source].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Feature' OR [Source].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Task' OR [Source].[System.WorkItemType] = ''Product Backlog Item'" and you`ll get the result: Feature-> Product Backlog Item->Task->Task; Product Backlog Item->Task->Task; Task->Task