# how to find all the Sprint's bugs,Feature,Task work in TFS by WIQL C# code?

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops, wiql

i want to find the Query to find all the `bugs,Task,Feature,Stories`
of all the sprints of both my team.
i have 2 team in my Project name "**MRI_Scrum_GIt**" which cantains 2 team **Phoneix and SS** and these 2 teams contains there Respected sprints(which is going on or done) 

and how to get all the Teams invloved in the Project(Query) in  my case SS and phoniex of MRI_Scrum

[image]

Comment: Do you want to get just plain list or tree of work items?

Comment: tree @ShamrayAleksander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created query with group operation instead operation "In":

[image]

For my project wiql in saved query is:

> SELECT [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State], [System.Tags] FROM WorkItemLinks WHERE ([Source].[System.TeamProject] = 'VSTSScrum'  AND ( [Source].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Bug'  OR  [Source].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Product Backlog Item'  OR  [Source].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Feature' ) AND ( [Source].[System.IterationPath] UNDER 'VSTSScrum\SS'  OR  [Source].[System.IterationPath] UNDER 'VSTSScrum\Phoneix' )) And ([System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward') And ([Target].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Task'  OR  [Target].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Product Backlog Item') ORDER BY [System.Id] mode(Recursive)

Source code for your request:

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace QueryLinkedWIQL
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WorkItemStore _wistore = new WorkItemStore("http://server/collection");

            string _teamProject = "VSTSScrum";
            string _teamPhoneixRootIteration = "VSTSScrum\\Phoneix";
            string _teamSSRootIteration = "VSTSScrum\\SS";

                string _wiql = string.Format("SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItemLinks WHERE ([Source].[System.TeamProject] = '{0}'"+ 
                "AND ( [Source].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Bug'  OR  [Source].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Product Backlog Item'  OR  [Source].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Feature' ) " + 
                "AND ( [Source].[System.IterationPath] UNDER '{1}'  OR  [Source].[System.IterationPath] UNDER '{2}' )) " + 
                "And ([System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward') And " + 
                "([Target].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Task'  OR  [Target].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Product Backlog Item') ORDER BY [System.Id] mode(Recursive)",
                _teamProject, _teamPhoneixRootIteration, _teamSSRootIteration);

            Query _query = new Query(_wistore, _wiql);

            WorkItemLinkInfo[] _links = _query.RunLinkQuery();

            foreach(WorkItemLinkInfo _link in _links)
            {
                //process link info item ....
            }
        }
    }
}
```

==============================

If you do not know all your teams. You can find them like here:[Add teams and team members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/scale/multiple-teams)

In this case all your teams have to have default iteration "ProjectName\IterationName".

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace QueryLinkedWIQL
{
    class Program
    {
        static List<string> ListTeams(TfsTeamProjectCollection pTpc, Project pProject)
        {
            TfsTeamService _teamService = pTpc.GetService<TfsTeamService>();
            var _teams = _teamService.QueryTeams(pProject.Uri.ToString());
            return (from t in _teams select t.Name).ToList();
        }

        static string ConstructTeamsString(string pProjectName, List<string> pTeamNames)
        {
            string _val = "";

            for(int  i = 0; i< pTeamNames.Count; i++)
                if (pTeamNames[i] == "SS" || pTeamNames[i] == "Phoneix") // I have many teams without iteration root name. So I use this if to remove unneeded teams. You can remove this line
                    _val += ((_val != "") ? " OR " : "") + string.Format("[Source].[System.IterationPath] UNDER '{0}\\{1}'", pProjectName, pTeamNames[i]);

            return _val;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string _teamProject = "VSTSScrum";

            TfsTeamProjectCollection _tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://server/collection"));

            WorkItemStore _wistore = _tpc.GetService<WorkItemStore>();

            string _teamsStr = ConstructTeamsString(_teamProject, ListTeams(_tpc, _wistore.Projects[_teamProject]));

            string _wiql = string.Format("SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItemLinks WHERE ([Source].[System.TeamProject] = '{0}'"+ 
                "AND ( [Source].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Bug'  OR  [Source].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Product Backlog Item'  OR  [Source].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Feature' ) " + 
                "AND ( {1} )) " + 
                "And ([System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward') And " + 
                "([Target].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Task'  OR  [Target].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Product Backlog Item') ORDER BY [System.Id] mode(Recursive)",
                _teamProject, _teamsStr);

            Query _query = new Query(_wistore, _wiql);

            WorkItemLinkInfo[] _links = _query.RunLinkQuery();

            foreach(WorkItemLinkInfo _link in _links)
            {
                //process link info item ....
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and how to get all the Teams invloved in the Project(Query) in my case SS and phoniex of MRI_Scrum

Comment: one last Question i want all the iteration Feature task,bugs and Stories that lie from 1st Dec 2017 to 29 feb 2018.

Comment: What is "Lie"? They was created between 1st Dec 2017 to 29 feb 2018?

Comment: q1. what if i only know project name and want to find all the Team names.

Comment: q2.if i know the team name and project name i want all the iterations

Comment: i want the team names in my Project MRI_Scrum (i have given name  SS phoneix for eg:) as i know it what if i don't know the name of the team i want the team names for the Project user enters ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49022991/how-to-get-a-task-id-storyid-featureid-feature-name-by-wiql-in-c-sharp-by-1-qu here is it